# What's the correct way to assign one GPU memory buffer value from another GPU memory buffer with some arithmetic on each source buffer's element?

Tags: c++, cuda, tensorrt

I'm a newbie for GPU programming using Cuda toolkit, and I have to write some code offering the functionality as I mentioned in the title.

I'd like to paste the code to show what exactly I want to do.

```
void CTrtModelWrapper::forward(void **bindings,
                               unsigned height,
                               unsigned width,
                               short channel,
                               ColorSpaceFmt colorFmt,
                               PixelDataType pixelType) {

    uint16_t *devInRawBuffer_ptr = (uint16_t *) bindings[0];
    uint16_t *devOutRawBuffer_ptr = (uint16_t *) bindings[1];

    const unsigned short bit = 16;
    float *devInputBuffer_ptr = nullptr;
    float *devOutputBuffer_ptr = nullptr;

    unsigned volume = height * width * channel;
    common::cudaCheck(cudaMalloc((void **) &devInputBuffer_ptr, volume * getElementSize(nvinfer1::DataType::kFLOAT)));
    common::cudaCheck(cudaMalloc((void **) &devOutputBuffer_ptr, volume * getElementSize(nvinfer1::DataType::kFLOAT)));

    unsigned short npos = 0;
    switch (pixelType) {

        case PixelDataType::PDT_INT8: // high 8bit
            npos = bit - 8;
            break;
        case PixelDataType::PDT_INT10:  // high 10bit
            npos = bit - 10;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    switch (colorFmt) {

        case CFMT_RGB: {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < volume; ++i) {
                devInputBuffer_ptr[i] = float((devInRawBuffer_ptr[i]) >> npos);   // SEGMENTATION Fault at this line
            }
        }
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }

    void *rtBindings[2] = {devInputBuffer_ptr, devOutputBuffer_ptr};
    // forward
    this->_forward(rtBindings);

    // convert output
    unsigned short ef_bit = bit - npos;
    switch (colorFmt) {

        case CFMT_RGB: {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < volume; ++i) {
                devOutRawBuffer_ptr[i] = clip< uint16_t >((uint16_t) devOutputBuffer_ptr[i],
                                                     0,
                                                     (uint16_t) pow(2, ef_bit)) << npos;
            }
        }
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

- `bindings` is a pointer to an array, the 1st element in the array is a device pointer that points to a buffer allocated using `cudaMalloc` on the gpu, each element in the buffer is a 16bit integer.the 2nd one the same, used to store the output data.
- `height`,`width`,`channel`,`colorFmt(RGB here)`,`pixelType(PDT_INT8, aka 8bit)` respective to the image height, width,channel number, colorspace, bits to store one pixel value.

the `_forward` function requires a pointer to an array, similar to `bindings` except that each element in the buffer should be a 32bit float number.

so I make some transformation using a loop

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < volume; ++i) {
                devInputBuffer_ptr[i] = float((devInRawBuffer_ptr[i]) >> npos);   // SEGMENTATION Fault at this line
            }
```

the `>>` operation is because the actual 8bit data is stored in the high 8 bit.

SEGMENTATION FAULT occurred at this line of code `devInputBuffer_ptr[i] = float((devInRawBuffer_ptr[i]) >> npos);` and `i` equals 0.

I try to separate this code into several line:

```
uint16_t value = devInRawBuffer_ptr[i];
float transferd = float(value >> npos);
devInputBuffer_ptr[i] = transferd;
```

and SEGMENTATION FAULT occurred at this line `uint16_t value = devInRawBuffer_ptr[i];`

I wonder that is this a valid way to assign value to an allocated gpu memory buffer?

PS: the buffer given in `bindings` are totally fine. they are from host memory using `cudaMemcpy` before the call to `forward` function, but I still paste the code below

```
    nvinfer1::DataType type = nvinfer1::DataType::kHALF;

    HostBuffer hostInputBuffer(volume, type);
    DeviceBuffer deviceInputBuffer(volume, type);

    HostBuffer hostOutputBuffer(volume, type);
    DeviceBuffer deviceOutputBuffer(volume, type);
// HxWxC --> WxHxC
    auto *hostInputDataBuffer = static_cast<unsigned short *>(hostInputBuffer.data());
    for (unsigned w = 0; w < W; ++w) {
        for (unsigned h = 0; h < H; ++h) {
            for (unsigned c = 0; c < C; ++c) {
                hostInputDataBuffer[w * H * C + h * C + c] = (unsigned short )(*(ppm.buffer.get() + h * W * C + w * C + c));
            }
        }
    }

    auto ret = cudaMemcpy(deviceInputBuffer.data(), hostInputBuffer.data(), volume * getElementSize(type),
                          cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (ret != 0) {
        std::cout << "CUDA failure: " << ret << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    void *bindings[2] = {deviceInputBuffer.data(), deviceOutputBuffer.data()};

    model->forward(bindings, H, W, C, sbsisr::ColorSpaceFmt::CFMT_RGB, sbsisr::PixelDataType::PDT_INT8);
```

Comment: By default, GPU memory is not accessible by cpu code, which is why a segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CUDA, it's generally not advisable to dereference a device pointer in host code.  For example, you are creating a "device pointer" when you use `cudaMalloc`:

```
common::cudaCheck(cudaMalloc((void **) &devInputBuffer_ptr, volume * getElementSize(nvinfer1::DataType::kFLOAT)));
```

From the code you have posted, it's not possible to deduce that for `devInRawBuffer_ptr` but I'll assume it also is a device pointer.

In that case, to perform this operation:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < volume; ++i) {
            devInputBuffer_ptr[i] = float((devInRawBuffer_ptr[i]) >> npos);  
        }
```

You would launch a CUDA kernel, something like this:

```
// put this function definition at file scope
__global__ void shift_kernel(float *dst, uint16_t *src, size_t sz, unsigned short npos){
  for (size_t idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x, idx < sz; idx += gridDim.x*blockDim.x) dst[idx] = (float)((src[idx]) >> npos);
}
// call it like this in your code:
kernel<<<160, 1024>>>(devInputBuffer_ptr, devInRawBuffer_ptr, volume, npos);
```

(coded in browser, not tested)

If you'd like to learn more about what's going on here, you may wish to study CUDA.  For example, you can get most of the basic concepts [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c/) and by studying the CUDA sample code `vectorAdd`.  The grid-stride loop is discussed [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and documents, it's really helpful !!